# how to understand complex sentence using as?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, as

> He doesn’t sound nearly as eager to make small talk with this guy as he was with me.

How to parse and understand the above sentence?

Comment: Compare to “My daughter is as tall as I am.”  What is it about your example that’s giving you trouble?

Comment: **as X as Y** is a construction that gives many learners trouble.  Have you checked for other answers here that might help?

Comment: What parts of the sentence do you already understand? What part of the sentence are you having trouble with? What do you think it might mean?